# Why does sorting in Emacs produce a different output from sorting in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, emacs

Why does sorting in Emacs vs bash produce differing outputs? What can I do to get the same result in both?

This is the output of diff two files, one sorted in Emacs with `sort-lines`, and the other in bash with `sort` command:

```
25a26,28
> /perl5/Filter/Crypto.pm
> /perl5/Filter/Crypto/CryptFile.pm
> /perl5/Filter/Crypto/Decrypt.pm
29,32d32
< /perl5/Filter/Crypto/CryptFile.pm
< /perl5/Filter/Crypto/Decrypt.pm
< /perl5/Filter/Crypto.pm
```

Comment: Could you redo the diff with `diff -u`? That would make it easier to read.

Comment: I found LANG=C solves the problem, but I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the language with the LANG environment variable determines (amongst others) the collation settings, that is, the sorting order of characters. Probably in your original LANG setting, the order of `/` and `.` is reversed w.r.t. the default `LANG=C`.